# Django TinyMCE Image Upload

Tags: javascript, python, django, tinymce

I have TinyMCE in my Django website, without using Django App called django-tinyMCE, i just used CDN because app has problems with admin panel, anyways i'm trying to select and upload image from editor, by adding image plugin from init function because its uses image source a url by default. this is what i have:

```
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
    tinymce.init({
     selector:'textarea',
     plugins: [
     "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
     "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
     "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
   ],

   file_browser_callback: function(field_name, url, type, win) {
     // file upload callback
   }
});
```

so how can i select and upload image with django using Tiny-MCE, can you show me exactly how its done? i'm confused